# Accessing the UIScrollView within UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm dealing with a bad UI design not of my making. I need to use UIPageViewController, but the upper half of the screen should receive swipes for UIPageViewController and the lower half of the screen should receive swipes for a different control. To do this, I'll need to set the frame of the UIPageViewController's built-in UIScrollView, I assume, so it is shorter. Is this possible? I don't mind traversing its view hierarchy to find the UIScrollView, but is that wrong or unseemly?

Comment: are you trying to achieve some kinda slideshow of images only ?

Comment: "To do this, I'll need to set the frame of the UIPageViewController's built-in UIScrollView" I don't see why, or what good you imagine that would do. Why don't you just put something over the front of the lower half so you can interfere with the swipes gesture recognition? Also note that you _do_ have access to the page view controller's own gesture recognizers, and can repoint them.

Comment: @matt What do you mean repoint them? Can I limit crop their effective area?